# Why is PHP always redirecting to the same page?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have written this small php page which should redirect users by the value put in the url. But the script does not seem to work. Anything i have missed?

```
<?php
if ($choice=="stb")
  $redirect="http://www.webpage1.com/";

    elseif ($choice=="player")
        $redirect="http://www.alternativewebpage.com/"; 

    else
        $redirect="http://www.world-tvpro.com/";

header( 'Location: '.$redirect ) ;
?>
```

If the page is saved at my server as script.php I would execute it like this: http://mypage.com/script.php?choice=stb .. Expected then is to be redirected to www.webpage1.com, but i get redirected to http://www.world-tvpro.com/ no matter what i write.

Comment: Where do you define `$choice`?

Comment: try $_GET['choice] instead of $choice

Comment: @andrewsi Choice is an illusion.

Comment: You should get choice by `$choice = $_GET['choice']`

Comment: Also, *please* don't be lazy and use the damn braces `{}` even if you can omit them.

Comment: @NullUserException using {} is way over-rated...

Comment: @nathanhayfield Uh... No, it isn't. Some time in the future someone decides to add a statement to the else block, and forgets to add the braces. A bit further down the line, you have a mysterious bug that could take hours of debugging time, just because some lazy bastard decided it would be good to save 2 seconds and omit the braces. This happened to me and ever since I've made it a point to bug everyone who's too lazy to add the damn braces.

Comment: come over to the dark side my friend...

Comment: @nathanhayfield Give me one good reason why you *shouldn't* add braces.

Comment: 1. readability...too many braces makes it annoying to read someone else's code     2. python (a good example of no braces is more readable)  3. lack of braces is why switch statements look cleaner than if else if else

Comment: @nathanhayfield 1) That's highly debatable. I find the lack of braces annoying and hard to read (especially if you butcher the indentation - very common). 2) How is Python an example of why braces are terrible? In Python indentation is important (and serve the same purpose braces do); in PHP indentation is syntactically meaningless. 3) `switch` statements, unlike if statements with no braces, have clear delimiters, the `:` in `case x:` and the `break` statement. Not the same thing.

Comment: Bad indentation, too. [Try Python](http://try-python.appspot.com/).

Comment: @nathanhayfield Although I'm a Python coder, I wouldn't say "no braces is more readable". I'd say "no braces is beautiful". But here (php), "no braces is dangerous".

Comment: @nathanhayfield Also, 1,2,3 are the same - "readability", and equally wrong. When the entire code contains blocks inside braces (as is typical in a php program) a lone block *without* braces is inconsistent and hence less readable.

Answer (score 1):

You are depending on a feature called `register_globals`, which is dangerous. Rather than letting query string parameters set globals in your script, use the `$_GET` superglobal:

```
if ( isset($_GET['choice']) && $_GET['choice'] === 'stb' ) {
```

For example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_GET['choice']` (or `isset($_GET['choice']) ? $_GET['choice'] : null`).

Comment: I dont see how the script would be put together with $_GET? How would i do a redirect and the if/else-statement? Please, could you make it clearer? Maybe modify the script if possible?

Comment: As you said you are getting `choice (blahblah.com?choice=132)` from url so that choice can be get into a php variable via `$_GET['choice']`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, sometimes not using { } around your statements can cause issues.

```
<?php
if ($_GET['choice'] == "stb")
{
    $redirect="http://www.webpage1.com/";
} elseif ($_GET['choice'] == "player") {
    $redirect="http://www.alternativewebpage.com/"; 
} else {
    $redirect="http://www.world-tvpro.com/";
}
header( 'Location: '.$redirect );
?>
```

Also, $_GET['choice'] is how you get variables from the url query string.

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses a series of super global arrays to pass information from the client to the server. They are as follows:

```
 $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE and $_REQUEST
```

In your case, since your passing the value in the url as a query parameter you should retrieve choice using $_GET:

```
$choice = $_GET['choice'];
```

Note: It can also be retrieved using $_REQUEST as request is a super global array containing all the values of $_GET, $_POST, and $_COOKIE.

You would simply do the same as above just with request:

```
$choice = $_REQUEST['choice'];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you add: `$choice = isset($_GET['choice']) ? $_GET['choice'] : false;` above the entire `IF` statement, then the code should be fine.

Also, while the IF statement is fine, a case statement could work nicely as well:

```
$choice = isset($_GET['choice']) ? $_GET['choice'] : false;
switch($choice){
    case "stb":
        $redirect = 'http://www.webpage1.com/'; break;
    case "player":
        $redirect = 'http://www.alternativewebpage.com/'; break;
    default:
        $redirect = 'http://www.world-tvpro.com/';
}
header("Location: ".$redirect);
exit;
```